# Enabling timer1 10-bit mode in ATtiny261

Tags: microcontroller, timer, microchip, atmel

I am having trouble enabling timer1 in 10-bit mode on a ATtiny261.

The datasheet only says that if any non-zero value is written to the TC1H temporary register the 10-bit mode is enabled, but it's not working for me. My test code is below:

```c
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= (1 << DDB5);        // B5 output (OC1D)
    TCCR1C |= 0x09;             // PWMD Enable with Cleared on Compare Match (non-invert)
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10);      // enable Timer/Counter1 with 1 prescale f ~ CLK/256
    
    TC1H = 0x01;
    OCR1D = 0x58;
    
    while (1) 
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

```
TC1H  |= 0x01;
TCNT1 |= 0xFF;
```

but it should actually be

```
TC1H  = 0x01;
TCNT1 = 0xFF;
```

and you might think that shouldn't make a difference, or at least it should leave *some* nonzero value in the high half of the register, but actually because of the way TC1H is latched it makes all the difference.

Per the datasheet, whenever TCNT1 is written, the value in TC1H goes along with it to provide the high four bits of the register; and whenever TCNT1 is read from, TC1H is updated as well. Now consider a pseudocode version of what happens with the `|=` operators:

```
tmp = TC1H;
tmp = tmp | 0x01;
TC1H = tmp;       // So far, so good. First statement completed.

tmp = TCNT1;      // Oops, we just overwrote TC1H by reading TCNT1!
tmp = tmp | 0xFF;
TCNT1 = tmp;      // And now we write back the high-byte that was already in the register.
```

You need to be careful when working with these register pairs, and a little typo can have a bigger impact than you might think.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  First I tried as you suggested but as soon as I write it like this: OCR1D = 0x18; it doesn't even work in 8 bit mode. The must be some other mistake too.

Comment: @Tom29 oh, yeah, a few things. Your bit-clearing code in `TIMER1_COMPD_VECT` is wrong, for one (it clears every bit of PORTB *except* PB5). Is there a reason why you're using normal mode and interrupt handlers to toggle the output, rather than setting fast PWM mode and letting the chip do it for you?

Comment: I updated the test code. It's still running in 8-bit mode. The write in the 10-bit register was successful as no compare match occurs if the value is bigger than 255. Please help me enable the 10-bit mode.

Comment: @Tom29 there is no 8-bit mode. TIMER1 is always 10-bit.

Comment: But it's only counting to 255 and then resets. No compare match occurs if the value in  OCR1D is bigger than 255. This is only what the datasheet says:
"if the two MSBs of the 10-bit registers are written to
zero the Timer/Counter1 is working as an 8-bit Timer/Counter"

Comment: @Tom29 sure, that just means "if you set all the values to things that fit in 8 bits, you can pretend the other two don't exist". There's still no separate 8-bit and 10-bit modes. I think the problem in your new code is that you're not setting OCR1C. It defaults to 255.

Comment: Yes thats right. This is what I was missing. I didn't realize that there is no OC1C, only A, B, D and that register do something else. Thank you very much.